# How to pack a jar in root directory of a war

Tags: maven

I have a war and I want to put one jar inside the war (Root directory), not inside the lib. I tried in `<jarmodule>` "bundleDir". But it didn't work. Excepted structure as below

```
A.War
  --- META_INF
  ----WEB_INF
  ----b.jar
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do that? And where is that jar coming from? Is it a dependency?

Comment: i'm using maven 3.0. Actually the A.war i packed inside a ear. And few classes packed inside application lib (suppose x.jar), packed in b.jar also.These classes having same package structure and class name (webservice) . So if we pack b.jar inside the A.war lib , invoke virtual exception is coming. so we packed out side lib .

Comment: This is really unclear. What exactly do you want to do? Is `b.jar` a Maven dependency? It sounds like you want to _exclude_ that dependency rather than having it in the root of the war.

Comment: WAR's don't support jar files in root folder..which will not being recognize by   things like tomcat etc...Furthermore it sounds like you are talking about an EAR file cause (jarmodule)..? Are your really using Maven 3.0 ? Not things like Maven 3.0.5 ?